# some misunderstand about student distribution and R

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I see on book :
 $t_{0.025,59}$ = 2.009
But when call qt in R. We have this result:

> qt(0.025,59)
>   [1] -2.000995

I don't know why have different in here.

As I think,  $t_{0.025,59}$ must is negative . Because it belongs left tail of distribution.

Anyone know clearly about this. Please help me.

Comment: This value has to be negative. Note that the t distribution "looks similar" to the normal distribution, and qnorm(0.025,0,1) gives -1.959964

Comment: I know, but in the many books, we can take it from the table. In here, it is positive. I don't understand that point

Answer (score 0):

The difference is likely due to a lack of care in being explicit. R gives the correct value.

I can only make guesses as to why your book has what it does. Some books I've seen use a context-dependent interpretation of the test statistic. For example, when some books are talking about a right-tailed hypothesis test, they might write:

$$t_{\alpha,df}$$

instead of the correct right-tailed test:

$$t_{1 -\alpha,df}$$

This isn't correct to do, and it's really sloppy, but it's a habit even I get into. I know that the z-value for p = 0.025 in the tails is 1.96. In my head, I have the association:

$$z_{\alpha=0.025} = 1.96$$

I correct the sign depending on the context, but I recall it in a not technically-correct manner. I suspect that your book might have done the same.